# How to integrate maven plugin to xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5, maven-plugin

I'm using Xcode 5, I need to add Maven plug to the Xcode, share me your knowledge on maven plugin add to the Xcode, what is the process and explain me step by step procedure.

Comment: xcode 5? the current xcode version is already Version 10